# What the blind can sea?

Tags: cipher

For the smart people here.
A code. Good luck. Feel free to ask questions,but only yes no and maybe.
What am I?

Ox.xo.oo

Xo.oo.oo
Xx.oo.xo

Xo.oo.oo

Xo.xx.xo
Xo.ox.oo
Xx.ox.oo

Xo.xx.oo
Xo.ox.oo
Xo.xx.xo
Xo.xx.xo
Ox.xo.oo
Xx.ox.xo
Xx.xx.oo

Comment: Is this related to Morse code?

Comment: Close.the title is a clue.no...

Comment: Oh, Braille script is it ?

Comment: Looks around suspiciously.

Comment: Yes or no? Should I put it as an answer or is there more to this question, like decoding the script ?

Comment: @JohnMiao Nice idea, but I think the title-hint was too much of a spoiler. From experience:You would be surprised of what 'the users' here on site manage to find/crack. Next time: Have faith and dare the community with more difficult questions/less hints (at first, at least)

Comment: Ok... I'm working on a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code and answer I got was:

> I Am A Red Herring

Why?

> Ox.xo.oo = I
>
> Xo.oo.oo = A
>
> Xx.oo.xo = M
>
> Xo.oo.oo = A
>
> Xo.xx.xo = R
>
> Xo.ox.oo = E
>
> Xx.ox.oo = D
>
> Xo.xx.oo = H
>
> Xo.ox.oo = E
>
> Xo.xx.xo = R
>
> Xo.xx.xo = R
>
> Ox.xo.oo = I
>
> Xx.ox.xo = N
>
> Xx.xx.oo = G
>
> I found this with this photo:
>   [image]
>
> X = the black dot and o = A blank dot

Comment: please explain (in spoiler tags) how you decoded it

Comment: What the **blind** can **sea** like my pun?

Comment: Yea I get it. Nice pun.